# How to set the Id value using Android NFC NdefRecord / NdefMessage methods

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

Is there a way to set the Id value in the NFC NdefRecord individually? There appears to be a hole in the API since there is an NdefRecord.getId() method but there is no equivalent NdefRecord.setID().

There are several methods to create an NdefRecord however, none of them have the Id field. For example, 
public static NdefRecord createExternal(String domain, String type, byte[] data);
Allows setting the domain & type but no Id field.

Also, it is annoying that the NdefRecord.getType() method returns the entire
String (domain + type) rather than simply the type that is set.

Answer (score 0):

No, once created an `NdefRecord` object is read-only. That's not only the case for the ID field but also for all other fields.

I guess the reason that the `create*()` methods do not have an option to set the ID field is that the ID field in NDEF records (it's purpose is to create references between multiple records) is rarely used.

What you could do is to create your record without the ID field:

```
NdefRecord tempRecord = NdefRecord.createExternal("example.com", "mytype", myPayload);
```

And then create a new instance from the values obtained from that record and including your ID field:

```
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(tempRecord.getTnf(), tempRecord.getType(), myId, tempRecord.getPayload());
```

The reason why `getType()` returns the whole Type field (including the domain) is that the `NdefRecord` object is a simple and generic wrapper around any NDEF record (no matter if it is an external type record or something else) and just returns the value that's actually contained in the binary representation of the record. Returning only the domain-specific type name would not make ases as there would be no way to know how to interpret it. In my opinion it would make more sense if the `getType()` method actually returned the full canonical type URN "urn:nfc:ext:example.com:mytype".